# Can't find documet scanner application that replaced the simple scan application

Tags: 19.10, scanner, document

I just installed 19.10 and the simple scan application was replaced with Document Scanner application but neither of then can be found or installed from software ubuntu shop. How to install this utility? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package for the Simple Scan Utility is named [`simple-scan`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=simple-scan).

You have to install it with command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simple-scan
```

And what is interesting - its *simple-scan.desktop* file contains name *Document Scanner* in the `Name` field. So it is a new name for the  *Simple Scan* (`simple-scan`) utility.