Scanner not detected in simple-scan in Ubuntu 24.04
I recently re-installed my OS, upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04. After re-installing simple-scan, my Fujitsu (Ricoh) fi-800r, connected directly by USB, is no longer detected by simple-scan, my preferred scanning software. This configuration worked OK in the prior 22.04 installation.
Notes

Installed latest drivers from the Ricoh website (pfufs/now 2.8.0 amd64 [installed,local])

ls /usr/lib/sane/ shows libsane-pfufs.so  libsane-pfufs.so.1  libsane-pfufs.so.1.1.24


lsusb reports my scanner at Bus 009 Device 005: ID 04c5:15fc Fujitsu, Ltd
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/*/* reports sufficient permissions crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root root 189, 1028 Aug 28 09:40 /dev/bus/usb/009/005
SANE documents the scanner as supported here.

From apt list *sane*:
libsane-common/noble,noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 all [installed]
libsane-dev/noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 amd64 [installed]
libsane-dev/noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 i386 [installed]
libsane-hpaio/noble,now 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libsane1/noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 amd64 [installed]
libsane1/noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 i386 [installed,automatic]
sane-airscan/noble,now 0.99.29-0ubuntu4 amd64 [residual-config]
sane-utils/noble,now 1.2.1-7build4 amd64 [installed]
sane/noble,now 1.0.14-18 amd64 [installed]
xsane-common/noble,noble,now 0.999-12ubuntu4 all [installed,automatic]
xsane/noble,now 0.999-12ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]

From sane-find-scanner:

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5, product=0x15fc) at libusb:005:003
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

From scanimage -L:
device `pfufs:fi-800R:009:005' is a  fi-800R scanner


/etc/sane.d/dll.conf has fujitsu (not commented out)

/etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf has usb 0x04c5 0x15fc


xsane can successfully scan images.
Opening simple-scan does not list my scanner in the drop down.
Opening simple-scan pfufs:fi-800R:009:005 times out when trying to start a scan.

Resources I've already read

http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-fujitsu.5.html
http://origin.pfultd.com/downloads/IMAGE/fi/ubuntu/280/P2U3-0200-07ENZ0.pdf
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SANE/Scanner-specific_problems#Fujitsu_fi_series
Simple Scan cannot find scanner
Scanner Not detected by Simple Scan
Simple Scan not recognizing Canon LiDE 25
https://superuser.com/questions/1396187/sane-stopped-detecting-usb-scanner
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=394683


Did you install simple-scanner with apt or snap(i.e. the app store)? Can you try removing the one installed from app store, and install it with apt sudo apt install simple-scan?

I had used the snap, and I just uninstalled and reinstalled everything using apt and was able to detect/scan successfully! Feel free to repost as an answer, and I will happily give credit. Thank you.

Snaps are sandboxed, which may indeed block USB if the proper connections are not set up in the package YAML. Please report the issue to the snap packager so they can fix their bug.

@user535733 It seems that the snap package maintainer is canonical. How do you report an issue here https://snapcraft.io/install/simple-scan/ubuntu ?

@DavidElner Done!

The best place I know to report a bug in snap packaging is https://forum.snapcraft.io

One of the best written, thoroughly researched, questions I've read here.

This seems to be a bug related to snap packaging.
The solution is to remove the snap app of simple-scan from snap store, and reinstall the apt app. Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one.
sudo snap remove simple-scan
sudo apt install simple-scan


Good to know. I hope Canonical gives people warnings not to use Snap in cases like this. (Of course they won't warn you).

@WinEunuuchs2Unix I wish Canonical tested their new technologies before pushing them so aggressively. Ubuntu is not anymore what it used to be :sigh:

Agreed. I wish Canonical read the Ask Ubuntu website.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix Also, many apps are not working out of the box in 24.04 (includes all electron apps except VS Code. Also includes many apps using web technologies). Here is the fix https://askubuntu.com/q/1511654/124466

firstly, the snap is made private. That means, only if you explicitly run sudo snap install simple-scan the snap shouldn't be there. But, I guess, you went to the internet and searched for simple-scan linux.. and the result showed up for you. I'll let the team know about this issue. Secondly, can you kindly try once if this fixes your issue?
sudo snap connect simple-scan:raw-usb

Because raw-usb is a very privileged plug, it's not auto connected. And this command will manually connect it. Can you check if this fixes it? Is there any other log you also see? Can you kindly share it with us?

It gives me error: snap "simple-scan" is not installed.

It means you're not using the snap. So, it must not be a snap related issue. :(

Searching for simple-scan in App center it does not give me any snap, only Document Scanner in Debian packages. But it loses connection every second or third page scan. So, I am looking for a solution.

As I read here https://askubuntu.com/a/1205931/933309, the new name for the Simple Scan (simple-scan) utility is indeed Document Scanner.
HP photosmart 5520 printer with USB connection.

Because the snap is made unlisted. You can try it by this
sudo snap install simple-scan

I did and it does not detect my scanner at all. Moreover, now I have two Document Scanners installed.

Did you ran this after installing the snap?
sudo snap connect simple-scan:raw-usb

Yes, I did but nothing happened. So, I removed the snap Document Scanner. At least, the Debian package recognizes the scanner, although it loses connection after a while. I am still looking for a solution.

Can you kindly share the logs? Run the snap from the terminal by the command, snap run simple-scan and share us what error log is showing up?
